# Can't run js function by click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have try everething but i can't change button text by choosing some item in "Requirements" dropdown. Here is the [site](http://missioncf-odss.temp-dns.com/register/).

At the bottom of the page there is "Requirements" dropdown. **For each item i have onclick**:

```
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" onclick="qwerty()" role="presentation">
```

And I have **JS code**:

```
function qwerty() {
    if(jQuery('#role').val() != 'seeking-to-acquire-a-business') {
        jQuery("#ze-next").attr('value', 'Register');
    } else {
        jQuery("#ze-next").attr('value', 'Next');
    }
}
```

but text button still not changing when i choose "seeking to acquire a business" . Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: yes there is an  element with id role.

Comment: `('#role')` this element is Missing In Action

Comment: do you get any errors in your developer tools console?

Comment: why are you using dashes for the .val check?

Comment: Are sure that the onclick event is get into your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` not called when changing the value of `#role`.

use `change` event instead :

```
jQuery('#role').on('change',function(){
    qwerty();
});
```

or add `onchange` attribute in you `#role` element :

```
<select id="role" onchange="qwerty()" ...... >
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a framework to create the selects using other HTML - and the framework probably blocks all clicks and used them to own handling.

Try using other events, e.g.:

```
<li class="..." onmouseup="qwerty()" role="presentation">
```

This seems to work on your site.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>sample Page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script>
    function qwerty() {
        if ($('#role').val() != 'seeking-to-acquire-a-business') {
            $("#ze-next").attr('value', 'Register');
        } else {
            $("#ze-next").attr('value', 'Next');
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {


    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="role" value="seeking-to-acquire-a-business" />

    <input type="button" id="ze-next" />
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" onclick="qwerty()" role="presentation">test</li>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code through console and it works fine
[image]

It seems onclick event is not calling to your function.

So instead of onclick use

```
jQuery(document).on('change','#role', function(){
    if(jQuery('#role').val() != 'seeking-to-acquire-a-business') {
        jQuery("#ze-next").attr('value', 'Register');
    } else {
        jQuery("#ze-next").attr('value', 'Next');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this Demo Code:
HTML Code:

```
<select id="role">
  <option value="select">Choose</option>
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="Two">2</option>
  <option value="Three">3</option>
</select>

<button id="setValue">Set Value from Dropdown</button><!-- Sets Dropdown value to this button -->
<button id="setText">Set Text from Dropdown</button><!-- Sets Dropdown text to this button -->
```

JQuery Code

```
$("#role").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()!="select"){
   $("#setValue").text($(this).val());
   $("#setText").text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

`if(jQuery('#role').val() == 'seeking-to-acquire-a-business') {
    jQuery("#ze-next").attr('value', 'Register');
} else {
    jQuery("#ze-next").attr('value', 'Next');
}`